# Regex for permalink

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex for permalink.
Permalink will always start with `/`. And doesn't contain any special characters except hyphen, forwardslash.

Some of the random examples:

```
/qwerty
/asd-a1
/month/december
/posts/1
/users/id/1
/rand-om/text-1/word
```

Rejected examples(because of special chars or double forwardslash):

```
/december!@#
/holidays/jan&^
/happy//birthday
//calendar/third-week
```

I have tried answers on stackoverflow and weirdly none of them worked.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `/^\//`?

Comment: it accepts special characters. Is it allowed to have special characters? I don't think so..I'm newbie.

Comment: @JosephMarikle 's example simply says "the line starts with `/`, then anything goes. Seems like that's what you want, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a better example of your input data, but this works:

```
^(\/{1}[a-z0-9\-]{1,}[a-z0-9\-\/]*)$
```

Here is a working example using the data you provided: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xuMoQC/3)

Comment: any way to not allow any special characters except hyphen?

Comment: and I also don't want to allow double forwardslashes like: //dosomething or /birth//smith